# Powershell: Script execution time longer than individual commands

Tags: powershell

I am having an interesting problem

For simplicy sake I created a test script:

```
GET-CHILDITEM C:\TEST\*
```

When I run this command by itself at the prompt it runs in 44 milliseconds

The moment I run the script that has the exact same command it takes 15 SECONDS

This is happening on all my scripts. What could be happening? My attempts to google search this issue has only yielded how to optimize scripts or use of the start-sleep command.

Comment: How do you "run the script"? `powershell -file "path\to\script.ps1"`? `& .\path\to\script.ps1` from an already running prompt? Shortcut?

Comment: in an open prompt. ./script.ps1

Comment: That's weird. To troubleshoot, I'd suggest creating a completely empty script, and then use `Trace-Command` to see what happens: `Trace-Command -Expression { ./script.ps1 } -Name CommandDiscovery,CommandSearch,LocationGlobber,PathResolution,PSDriveInfo,TypeConversion -Option All -PSHost` - if you see a wait between outputs, it might indicate what's taking so long

Comment: Assuming `I run the script` means `powershell -file script.ps1` maybe you have a weird profile script that waits for 15 seconds. Try adding `-noprofile` option.

Comment: @Mathias this is the line that it stops on for 15 seconds: `DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Command Found: path (C:\test\test.ps1) is a script with name: test.ps1`